# How to add an address to an address?

Tags: c#, winforms, arrays, byte

I want to take say 0x82000000 and add say 1dcf to it so it would become 0x82001dcf or any address. How would I do this in the easiest way? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Why are you messing with addresses in winforms?

Comment: This has malicious written all over it.

Comment: actually this is for the xbox 360 sdk i need to be able to set values to the correct address for the applications running on the xbox

Answer (score 3):

using unsafe code:

```
public unsafe void Foo() {

    byte* start = (byte*)0x82000000;
    start += 0x1DCF;

}
```

Using IntPtr:

```
public void Foo() {

    IntPtr start = new IntPtr( 0x82000000 );
    Int64 value = start.ToInt64();
    value += 0x1DCF;

    IntPtr result = new IntPtr( value );

}
```